# SFMC Journey Re-Entry After Exit Is Not Working

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

I have set up a journey to have:

1. Re-entry only after exiting
2. A single email
3. 5-minute wait before exiting

The email gets sent and the first customer goes through the entire journey but if the same customer was queued while they were already in the journey. The wait between the completion of the first run and the second is much larger than 5 minutes, or it never runs. I am unsure since right now my wait time is over 2 hours and I haven't received anything.

**Response/Logging from SFMC**

1. API Response is `201` and `eventInstanceId` which refers to accepted requested.
2. SFMC Journey Event Results show:

- Contacts Evaluated: 3
- Contacts Accepted: 1
- Contacts Rejected: 0

3. SFMC Journey History Log show: `CurrentlyWaitingInSameInteraction`

Does anyone know if this is an active bug or intended functionality? Because to me it seems as if they are stuck in a queue. Thank you.

Comment: if you try to inject a subscriber while they were in a journey they would fail injection do to already in same interaction, they wouldn't queue, you would have to attempt to inject them again

Comment: Is this new or undocumented because 1) the API returns 201 which is the same as the success message and 2) the journey says 3 contacts evaluated; 1 contact accepted; 0 contacts rejected. The journey log says "CurrentlyWaitingInSameInteraction". I have no failure message from the API or in SFMC. I will add this to my question above.

Comment: @EazyE The documentation states that they go into a queue and that it should evaluate at the end of a wait period. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_status_key_reference.htm&type=5

Comment: once you get the status CurrentlyWaitingInSameInteraction  they are no longer queued

Comment: @EazyE Thanks. I get it immediately on the API request. I'm assuming this is a bug in journey builder and just have to work around it? Do you know if there's any way for me to request the status via API based on the event instance id that I receive? Otherwise I'll never know that it failed.

Comment: if you want them to enter change your re-entry status, or decrease the wait time to 1 min, this is expected behavior not a bug

Comment: It happens at 1 min as well. I'll just allow re-entry anytime. Thanks.

Comment: @EazyE Re-entry anytime is failing as well when the same subscriber wants to enter a journey in a short timeframe.